# Error when rendering svg

Tags: tex4ht, chemfig, svg

I'm trying to generate a svg image of a reaction mechanism. However I keep receiving the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfsys@svg@newline ->\Hnewline
```

when running the command `make4ht -u "Bromothymol_blue".tex` where `Bromothymol_blue` is the name of the latex document. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{mol2chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{tex4ht}
\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemname{\tiny\chemfig{-[:160]-[:100](-[:40]Br)(-[:220,,,,draw=none]\mcfcringle{1.3})-[:160](-[:100,,,1]OH)-[:220](-[:160](-[:100])-[:220])-[:280]-[:340](-[:40])-[:280]@{C}(-[:204]-[:274](-[:154,,,,draw=none]\mcfcringle{1.3})-[:214](-[:274](-[:214])-[:334])-[:154](-[:214,,,2]HO)-[:94](-[:154]Br)-[:34](-[:94])-[:334])-[:288]-[:240](-[:0,,,,draw=none]\mcfcringle{1.3})-[:300]--[:60]-[:120](-[:180])-[:72]S(=[:336]O)(=[:60]O)-[:144]O(-[:216])}}{Yellow}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[red](C) circle (0.1) +(120:0.1) ..controls +(120:0.5) and +(0:0.5).. +(155:2) node[left,align=right] {Conjugation\\stops\\here};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \arrow{<=>[\small\ce{+OH-}][\small\ce{H+},\;\ce{H2O}]}
    \chemname{\tiny\chemfig{
            % 15
            -[:300]% 14
            (
            -[::60]% 16
            )
            -[::300]% 12
            -[::300]% 11
            (
            -[::300]\mcfright{O}{^{\mcfminus}}% 17
            )
            -[::60]% 10
            (
            -[::300]Br% 18
            )
            -[::60]% 9
            (
            -[::300]% 19
            )
            -[::60]% 8
            (
            -[::60]% 13
            -[::60]% -> 12
            )
            (
            -[::120,,,,draw=none]\mcfcringle{1.3}% (o)
            )
            -[::300]% 7
            (
            -[::70]% 20
            -[::320]% 21
            (
            -[::310]S% 26
            (
            -[::110]\mcfright{O}{^{\mcfminus}}% 28
            )
            (
            =[::50]O% 29
            )
            =[::350]O% 27
            )
            (
            -[::120,,,,draw=none]\mcfcringle{1.3}% (o)
            )
            -[::60]% 22
            -[::60]% 23
            -[::60]% 24
            -[::60]% 25
            -[::60]% -> 20
            )
            =[::300]% 6
            -[::60]% 1
            (
            -[::60]% 35
            )
            -[::300,,,,drh]% 2
            (
            -[::60]Br% 34
            )
            -[::300]% 3
            (
            =[::60]O% 33
            )
            -[::300]% 4
            (
            -[::300,,,,drh]% 5
            -[::300]% -> 6
            )
            -[::60]% 30
            (
            -[::300]% 31
            )
            -[::60]% 32
    }}{Blue}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

I tried to follow the solution from [Latex to HTML conversion (basic explanation)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429638/latex-to-html-conversion-basic-explanation). I use TeXstudio and used the user command `make4ht -u %.tex`

Please note that I know the code works with pdftlatex and that is not what I am trying to do. I am trying to generate a html output with an svg using tex4ht. Also I am quite new to this so please try and explain as much as possible in your answer. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You encountered [an old bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185349/2891) in PGF. It was  fixed by a recent update, so you shouldn't get this error in up-to date TL 2018 or pretest of TL 2019.

But the real problem is that this source file doesn't work wit the default `tex4ht` anyway. It produces just some arrows. Fortunately, some alternative ways for TikZ support for `tex4ht` exist. First one is to use TikZ externalization, the second is to use an alternative `tex4ht` driver. The second alternative is easier to use. You need to install the [alternative driver](https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht) and modify your source file slightly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\ifdefined\HCode
    \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi 

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{mol2chemfig}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mhchem}
%\usepackage{tex4ht}
\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemname{\tiny\chemfig{-[:160]-[:100](-[:40]Br)(-[:220,,,,draw=none]\mcfcringle{1.3})-[:160](-[:100,,,1]OH)-[:220](-[:160](-[:100])-[:220])-[:280]-[:340](-[:40])-[:280]@{C}(-[:204]-[:274](-[:154,,,,draw=none]\mcfcringle{1.3})-[:214](-[:274](-[:214])-[:334])-[:154](-[:214,,,2]HO)-[:94](-[:154]Br)-[:34](-[:94])-[:334])-[:288]-[:240](-[:0,,,,draw=none]\mcfcringle{1.3})-[:300]--[:60]-[:120](-[:180])-[:72]S(=[:336]O)(=[:60]O)-[:144]O(-[:216])}}{Yellow}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[red](C) circle (0.1) +(120:0.1) ..controls +(120:0.5) and +(0:0.5).. +(155:2) node[left,align=right] {Conjugation\\stops\\here};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \arrow{<=>[\small\ce{+OH-}][\small\ce{H+},\;\ce{H2O}]}
    \chemname{\tiny\chemfig{
            % 15
            -[:300]% 14
            (
            -[::60]% 16
            )
            -[::300]% 12
            -[::300]% 11
            (
            -[::300]\mcfright{O}{^{\mcfminus}}% 17
            )
            -[::60]% 10
            (
            -[::300]Br% 18
            )
            -[::60]% 9
            (
            -[::300]% 19
            )
            -[::60]% 8
            (
            -[::60]% 13
            -[::60]% -> 12
            )
            (
            -[::120,,,,draw=none]\mcfcringle{1.3}% (o)
            )
            -[::300]% 7
            (
            -[::70]% 20
            -[::320]% 21
            (
            -[::310]S% 26
            (
            -[::110]\mcfright{O}{^{\mcfminus}}% 28
            )
            (
            =[::50]O% 29
            )
            =[::350]O% 27
            )
            (
            -[::120,,,,draw=none]\mcfcringle{1.3}% (o)
            )
            -[::60]% 22
            -[::60]% 23
            -[::60]% 24
            -[::60]% 25
            -[::60]% -> 20
            )
            =[::300]% 6
            -[::60]% 1
            (
            -[::60]% 35
            )
            -[::300,,,,drh]% 2
            (
            -[::60]Br% 34
            )
            -[::300]% 3
            (
            =[::60]O% 33
            )
            -[::300]% 4
            (
            -[::300,,,,drh]% 5
            -[::300]% -> 6
            )
            -[::60]% 30
            (
            -[::300]% 31
            )
            -[::60]% 32
    }}{Blue}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

This is the result in browser:

[image]

Comment: It appears that the circles within the benzene ring have been offput to the side. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: It appears that one svg file outputs correctly while the other with 0x at the end (`<filename>0x.svg`) is not outputted correctly and is the one included in the html output. Nonetheless I can use the correct one. Thanks so much

Comment: @sabhoque I can see that. It seems like an issue in the TikZ driver, but really weird one, as it uses just the dvips driver

Comment: would you know how to fix it?

Comment: @sabhoque unfortunately not. I've tried also `pgfsys-dvisvgm` and `pgfsys-dvips` drivers with `tex4ht` and they always produce shifted circles. I am not an expert on PGF and the graphic drivers, so I don't understand what is the issue.

Comment: @sabhoque I've updated the driver, it seems to fix the issue

Comment: Thank you I will be sure to reference you on my blog!

Comment: Is it possible to make it work for lulatex by any chance, there's some particular fonts I wanted to use using fontec. Otherwise I'll just convert the file through inkscape or similar, its just a bit more of a hassle.

Comment: @sabhoque sure, use the `-l` command line option

Comment: Like this `make4ht -u "Bromothymol_blue".tex` ?

Comment: @sabhoque `make4ht -u -l Bromothymol_blue.tex`